# Efectuar un evento charCode dentro de un evento keypress JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, razor

Dentro de mi codigo de `JavaScript` hago una petición ajax pero quiero que esta solo se ejecute cuando se aplican una serie de condiciones la primera que el valor ingresado solo sea numérico la segunda que el valor tenga cierta longitud mínima, tengo problemas evaluando la primera condición ya que no me toma la evaluación que le hago sobre el evento, o no se si lo estoy invocando de la manera adecuada.

JavaScript:

```html
$(document).ready(function () {
let CreditoValor = $('#Valor');
CreditoValor.keypress(function (event) {
        if (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57) {
            ValorActual = $(this).val();
            if (CreditoValor.val().length <= 5) {
                if (ValorActual < EnteroValorMinimoCredito) {
                    textoMedValor.css('display', 'block');
                    textoMedValor.text('El valor minimo es de: $' + ValorMinimoCampoNumber);
                }
            }
            else {
                RangoValorCredito.val($(this).val());
                ValorActual = $(this).val();
                ValorActualMultiplo = ValorActual % 1000;
                if (ValorActual > medValor) {
                    textoMedValor.css('display', 'block');
                    textoMedValor.text('Si es tú primera vez puedes pedir hasta' + ' ' + '$' + new Number(medValor).toLocaleString('es-CO'));
                }
                else {
                    textoMedValor.css('display', 'none');
                }
                if (ValorActualMultiplo != 0) {
                    textoMedValor.css('display', 'block');
                    textoMedValor.text('Introduce Multiplos de 1.000');
                }
                if (ValorActual > EnteroValorMaximoCredito) {
                    textoMedValor.css('display', 'block');
                    textoMedValor.text('El valor máximo es de: $' + ValorMaximoCampoNumber);
                }
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/CalcularSimulador',
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "html",
                    data: { Valor: RangoValorCredito.val(), Plazo: RangoPlazoCredito.val() },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#calculosSimulador').html(data);
                    },
                    error: function (ex) {
                        console.log('Insatisfactoria', ex);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
@Html.TextBox("Valor", @objCalculoCal.Valor.ToString(), new { @class = "inputText", @id = "Valor" })
```

Realmente no tengo problemas con la solicitud, el inconveniente surge cuando implemento la función `event.charCode` ya que cuando la íntegro el `input` deja de funcionar o no ejecuta las condiciones.

Comment: Haz un `console.log(event.charCode);` antes de realizar cualquier otra cosa dentro de la función, así sabrás si ese es realmente el problema o se trata de otra cosa.

Comment: Efectivamente es otra cosa, falla por el RangoValorCredito.val($(this).val()); ya que no puede capturar el momento actual al estar dentro de una función.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar una expresión regular para que valida que solo existen "Numeros" en el texto ingresado usando `RegExp` de javascript, para este caso cuando no es numero se elimina el ultimo carácter ingresado con la funcion `soloIngresaNumeros()` o si el usuario pega el valor retornara conservara solo numeros con `conservarSoloNumeros()`

```js
function validar(elinput){
   // ingresa por keyup
   soloIngresaNumeros(elinput)
   // ingresa por ctrl+v
   conservarSoloNumeros(elinput)
}

function soloIngresaNumeros(elinput){
  var texto = elinput.value
   var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]*$")
   if(false == regex.test(texto)){
     elinput.value = texto.substr(0,texto.length-1)
   }
}

function conservarSoloNumeros(elinput){
    var texto = elinput.value
    var nuevoTexto = ""
    var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]*$")
    for(t in texto){
      if(regex.test(texto[t])){
        nuevoTexto += texto[t]
      }
    }
    elinput.value = nuevoTexto
}
```

```html
<input onkeyup="validar(this)" value="0">
```